# What are the security differences between "NegotiateStream" and "WebRequest" using SPNego/Kerberos?

Tags: kerberos, windows-authentication, iis-8.5, spnego, gssapi

The following link describes [a traditional intranet client-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.negotiatestream?view=netframework-4.8) socket communication using Kerberos

```
public class NegotiateStream : System.Net.Security.AuthenticatedStream
... 
// Request authentication.
NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
NegotiateStream authStream = new NegotiateStream(clientStream, false); 
...
// Pass the NegotiateStream as the AsyncState object 
// so that it is available to the callback delegate.
IAsyncResult ar = authStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(
                  new AsyncCallback(EndAuthenticateCallback), authStream);
...
```

On the other hand, IIS has the ability to authenticate using what I understand to be "Kerberos with SPNego over SSL"... (please correct my terminology!).

When in this SPNego/SSL/Kerberos mode, I wasn't able to get `NegotiateStream` to work, however I was able to get the machineaccount$ to work correctly with `WebRequest.AuthenticationLevel` set to `MutualAuthRequired`

[image]

**Question**

- What is the security difference between using the `NegotiateStream`, versus `WebRequest.AuthenticationLevel`?
- What are the standards (such as [MS-SPNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-spng/f377a379-c24f-4a0f-a3eb-0d835389e28a)) being used in each solution?
- What are the Windows subsystems (SIP, GSS-API, etc) that are in use?

Any information that can help me integrate Linux agents into this Kerberos/SpNego solution would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about the differences in transport types. Here you have two different transports:

- Binary stream of arbitrary data
- HTTP stream of HTTP-encoded data

An HTTP request and response have very specific semantics about how you authenticate a request, and that is via the `Authorization: [scheme] [token]` header and initiated by a response header `WWW-Authenticate: [Scheme]`, where `[scheme]` is often `Negotiate`.

A binary stream is arbitrary and left to the implementor to do whatever they want.

The `Negotiate` scheme is a GSS compatible package which is a simple protocol that lets the client and server negotiate an internal authentication protocol like Kerberos or NTLM. In Windows land this is called an SSPI package.

A package, either GSS or SSPI, is made up of a set of functions that start or accept handshakes between parties, and then potentially encrypt/decrypt data between the two parties (it's optionally supported). These functions generate messages that can go across any transport and any form of transport can call these functions.

In the `WebRequest` case the class is smart enough to detect the `Negotiate` header and calls into the Windows SSPI functions to get a ticket, passing the package name. This relies primarily on Kerberos for protection of the ticket itself, but it doesn't protect anything else in the HTTP request so SSL/TLS is used.

In the `NegotiateStream` case the wire format is somewhat arbitrary, but bounded by the `Negotiate` handshake. The client will send just the negotiate init message across the wire, the server will respond, and if they agree you can start sending encrypted messages to each other.